# Looping through a custom query makes WordPress assume another template

Tags: functions, templates, query-posts

I am calling this code from my custom sidebar, in order to get related postings from the same category:

```
query_posts(array(
   'cat' => get_category_id(),
   'showposts' => 5,
   'post__not_in' => array(get_the_ID())
));

get_template_part('article-list'); // outputs the posts
```

This works. The `have_posts()`-loop inside of my article-list.php now only outputs 5 other postings from the category.

But this also causes a problem: No matter on what kind of page I am (single.php, index.php, ...), WordPress always assumes that I am in the category template. So `is_category()` always returns `true` after calling `query_posts('cat=...')`. Thus `is_single()` returns `false`, although the single.php-template is used.

What can I do to tell WordPress that it is still using the single-template?
Or: What other function can I use to detect which (main) view is loaded?

Comment: As you are resetting the main query... simply use `new WP_Query()`, `get_posts()` or one of the filters to alter the statement: `pre_get_posts`, `posts_clauses` (or similar). In short: There is (close to) no reason to ever use `query_posts()`. For more information about what happens, please refer to the answers at the linked question. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't even know that query_posts is that bad. Thanks, the other thread was really helpful.